# azure powershell cmdlet equivalent to aws powershell

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services

work mostly with aws and powershell but now need to start using azure.  What I need to do is the aws equivalent of new-ec2image.  which basically can capture a running or stopped vm and create an image for later use. Is there any equivalent command in azure powershell.
thanks
tr

Answer (score 0):

Save-AzureVMImage

```
Save OS or VM images from existing VMs. 
For capturing a VM Image, use the -OSState parameter.
```

*From `Get-Help Save-AzureVMImage -full`*

And here's a nice blog post on it:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/14/vm-image-blog-post/

..and a 2nd part:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/01/vm-image-powershell-how-to-blog-post/

Comment: well totally missed that one, thanks.  Now the only issue is that it won't do running vm's like aws's new-ec2image will.  Not a big deal, I usually don't use the noreboot option but its nice option to have.

Comment: -osstate "specialized" will do this without a reboot,  but warns against it which is exactly what the aws version basically does.  Would suspect that it would be the equivalent of a crash consistent backup.